# How do I take a overly used method and make into a static class that I can reimplement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Please will someone tell me how I can take a overly used method and make into a static class that I can reimplement? The code I am using is listed below:

```
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

I would like to place this code into a static class that I recall that class and reimpleament it throughout my project.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why aren't you placing that in your global.asax or using the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute?

Comment: You should need this statement 1x per project. Hardly "overly used". What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I have placed this into my Global.asax but asking this questions allows me to understand how to properly take a overused function and make into a static function that can be used multiple times.

Comment: I used this code about twice right now. Once in the global.asax during the launch of the website, I also use it when I am seeding my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a new class (doesn't need to be static), add a method and declare it static.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void DoSomething() {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

And in some other method, just do

```
MyClass.DoSomething();
```